Problem with deserialize string as enum in MessagePack
Previously, we exchanged between servers using JSON.
We decided to switch to MessagePack to save traffic and problems began with his capriciousness.
The fact is that one server (Java) sends another Enum as a string, but on this other server the Enum  is not a string, but realEnum.
Json calmly handled such cases, but MessagePack did not.
Can I add some attributes to the C# server to make everything work fine?
I wrote my attributes, but they don't look reliable.
[MessagePackFormatter(typeof(Common.MessagePack.NullableEnumAsStringFormatter<MapObjectType>))]


Test Code:
   public static readonly MessagePackSerializerOptions SerializerOptions =
        MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard
            .WithResolver(CompositeResolver.Create(
                BuiltinResolver.Instance,
                StandardResolver.Instance
            ))
        ;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var testClass1 = new TestClass1() { Value = "A" };
        var data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(testClass1, SerializerOptions);
        var testClass2 = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass2>(data, SerializerOptions);
    }

    [MessagePackObject]
    public class TestClass1
    {
       [Key("Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    [MessagePackObject]
    public class TestClass2
    {
       [Key("Value")]
        public MyEnum Value { get; set; }
    }

    public enum MyEnum
    {
        [EnumMember(Value = "A")]
        A,
        [EnumMember(Value = "B")]
        B
    }

I can fix the code above if i write
[MessagePackFormatter(typeof(EnumAsStringFormatter<MyEnum>))]

But how to fix this code?
[MessagePackObject]
class TestClass3
{
    [Key("Values")]
    public List<string> Values { get; set; }
}

[MessagePackObject]
class TestClass4
{
    [Key("Values")]
    public List<MyEnum> Values { get; set; }
}



   var testClass3 = new TestClass3() { Values = ["A"] };
    var data = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(testClass3, SerializerOptions);
    var testClass4 = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<TestClass4>(data, SerializerOptions);

